# How to get the domain name without www, subdomain, and com/net/org/etc

Tags: php, url, dns

I just need to get the domain name only form a url, (without com and everything else) example:

I have:

```
http://www.subdomain.domain1.com/
www.subdomain.domain2.net
subdomain.subdomain2.domain3.org/
http://domain4.com
```

I want to get with PHP:

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
domain4
```

Answer (score 8):

[parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

with the "PHP_URL_HOST" argument

then [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the "." and extract the penultimate element of the resulting array

Comment: But how to get the penultimate element? so I can update the post with the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware of possible urls with top level domains such as `.co.uk` (are those officially called top level as well, by the way?), etc., though.

Comment: @fireeyedboy Very good point!

Comment: It'll also not work if you have only the IP.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of [Shyam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918077/shyam) and employing the concept suggested by [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) to get the penultimate element of the namespace, I might suggest using a simpler regular expression that utilizes an *anchored lookahead* like the following:

```php
function get_domain($url) {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('/[\w-]+(?=(?:\.\w{2,6}){1,2}(?:\/|$))/', $url, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Matches

- `names` in `https://www.names.co.uk/`
- `domain1` in `http://www.subdomain.domain1.com/`
- `domain2` in `www.subdomain.domain2.net`
- `domain3` in `subdomain.subdomain2.domain3.org/`
- `domain4` in `http://domain4.com`
- `seventymm` in `http://www.seventymm.co.in/browse/buy-home-furnishing-bed-sheets-pack-of-3/2456/1/v2034/0/0/1/2/1/0/go`

Answer (score 0):

Shyam's answer is the best. You just have to make sure all the the URLs start with HTTP and add strtok at the end(see below). Here's another version using an array:

```
function get_domain($url)
    {
    $urlobj = parse_url($url);
    $domain = $urlobj['host'];
    if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs))
        {
        return $regs['domain'];
        }

    return false;
    }

$urls = array(
    'http://www.subdomain.domain1.com/',
    'http://www.subdomain.domain2.net',
    'http://subdomain.subdomain2.domain3.org/',
    'http://domain4.com'
);

// Using foreach + strtok to remove .[domain extensions]

echo "<ul>";

foreach($urls as $url)
    {
    echo "<li>" . strtok(get_domain($url),'.') . "</li>";
    }

echo "</ul>";
```

This will output:

- domain1
- domain2
- domain3
- domain4

P.S you can add strtok to the function as shown below:

```
function get_domain($url)
    {
    $urlobj = parse_url($url);
    $domain = $urlobj['host'];
    if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs))
        {
        return strtok($regs['domain'], '.');
        }

    return false;
    }
```

then:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://www.subdomain.domain1.com/',
    'http://www.subdomain.domain2.net',
    'http://subdomain.subdomain2.domain3.org/',
    'http://domain4.com'
);

// Using foreach

echo "<ul>";

foreach($urls as $url)
    {
    echo "<li>" . get_domain($url) . "</li>";
    }

echo "</ul>";
```

Minus ul/li:

```
 $urls = array(
        'http://www.subdomain.domain1.com/',
        'http://www.subdomain.domain2.net',
        'http://subdomain.subdomain2.domain3.org/',
        'http://domain4.com'
    );

    // Using foreach
    foreach($urls as $url)
        {
        echo get_domain($url)."<br>";
        }
```

Output:
domain1
domain2
domain3
domain4

Answer (score -5):

To get the domain , you can use `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`.

Explode the string with the subdomain you do not want to include.

Eg.
subdomain.domain.com

```
<?php
$add=explode('subdomain.',$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"])[1];
// $add = domain.com
?>
```

Comment: This is not a flexible solution - it only works when the subdomain is known.